# Laravel 8 How can i make the input type=text to using the validation unique : (table name)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and I created form like this

```
<form action="{{ route('pengaduan.verify-email') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    
    <img class="mb-4" src="/example/sign-in/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="72" height="57">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Verifikasi email</h1>

    <div class="form-floating">
        <input TYPE="TEXT" name="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" id="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus value="{{ old('email') }}"  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9#-+_.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
          @error('email')
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  {{ $message }}
              </div>
          @enderror
      </div>
  
    
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</main>
```

This input type actually is input type="email", because i want to using concatenation operator for my domain so i change the input type="text"

so the user just input their email name, example when they just input "stackoverflow" this input will auto return like this stackoverflow@mydomain.com

But when i use the input type text, this validation didn't work

```
   $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|unique:complaints', 
        ],
```

This is the code in my Controller:

```php
  public function verify(Request $request){
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
          'email' => 'required|unique:complaints', 
     ],
        [
           'email.unique' => 'This email is doing a Complaint. Wait for the complaint to be completed to make a       
   complaint again' 
  ]);


  $input = $request->email; 
  $university = '@university.com';
 $emailuniversity = $input .= $university; 

 $validatedData['email'] = $emailuniversity;

$validatedData['token'] = Str::random(127);


Complaint::create($validatedData);


$email =  $validatedData['email'];
    $data =[
        'content' => 'To make complaint click the button below',
        'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/complaint/create/'. $validatedData['token'],
    ];

  Mail::to($email)->send(new VerifyAlternative($data));

return redirect()->route('complaint.check')->with('success','Register Email Success. Please check your email to make new complaint');
```

Before I tried to change the input type to input type="email" and it's work

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not just let user enter their own email address, like is common with sign in forms?
However, what you could do is create a hidden input field, and before submitting the form, place the users text input with an emailaddress appended in there and submit that for validation.

Comment: is there an example to do that?

Comment: Probably not, but if you google how to get and set the value of inputs using Javascript you should get a long way.

Comment: This is possible, but quite a mess to do so. What do you mean by "But when i use the input type text, this validation didn't work"? what error did you get

Comment: You should add the @domain.com before validation if I understand you correctly. Try to take a look at this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/modify-input-value-before-validation

Answer (score 0):

Here's my full code in controller:

```
   public function verify(Request $request){
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
          'email' => 'required|unique:complaints', 
     ],
        [
           'email.unique' => 'This email is doing a Complaint. Wait for the complaint to be completed to make a       
   complaint again' 
  ]);


  $input = $request->email; 
  $university = '@university.com';
 $emailuniversity = $input .= $university; 

 $validatedData['email'] = $emailuniversity;

$validatedData['token'] = Str::random(127);


Complaint::create($validatedData);


$email =  $validatedData['email'];
    $data =[
        'content' => 'To make complaint click the button below',
        'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/complaint/create/'. $validatedData['token'],
    ];

  Mail::to($email)->send(new VerifyAlternative($data));

return redirect()->route('complaint.check')->with('success','Register Email Success. Please check your email to make new complaint');
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. I would like to let you know that you posted this as an answer. It's better to edit you question and add this to the question itself